# WearOS: same package name or same applicationId?

Tags: android, google-play, wear-os

The [docs for publishing WearOS apps](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging) consistently state that:

> Ensure that both the watch and phone app modules have the same **package name**.

However I'm wondering if it actually means **applicationId** from the build.gradle file instead of package name (my understanding of what package name means is in the package statement at the top of source files - maybe that's wrong?)

The reason I'm wondering this is that [another part of the docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id) say that:

> Every Android app has a unique application ID that looks like a Java package name, such as com.example.myapp. This ID uniquely identifies your app on the device and in Google Play Store. If you want to upload a new version of your app, the application ID (and the certificate you sign it with) must be the same as the original APK—if you change the application ID, Google Play Store treats the APK as a completely different app. So once you publish your app, you should never change the application ID.

So, it sounds like it's the applicationId that is important when publishing apps, not the package name. Maybe I'm getting my terminology confused, or maybe the terms 'package name' and 'applicationId' are used interchangeably?

Also, I'm futher confused by the fact that you can have a package attribute in the application element of Manifest (eg `package="com.example.myapp"`) - I currently don't have that so I assume it's optional.

I'm a bit confused, if anyone could clarify **what exactly is meant by package name** when it says `Ensure that both the watch and phone app modules have the same package name` that would be great.  Thanks :)

Comment: Ensure that both the watch and phone app modules have the same applicationId.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Why don't they say applicationId if they mean applicationId? Is it a synonym for package name?

Comment: Yes, they are the same thing. *Package name* is the terminology used in most places (manifest, the `PackageManager` class, most documentation, etc.), but for some reason they called it `applicationId` in build.gradle. Maybe just to confuse us. 